# How can I catch errors in middleware on nestjs

Tags: error-handling, nestjs

I am trying to catch errors with try-catch structure in middleware. I call next function in try block and if I have an error like null reference etc., I wait to catch the error in catch block. But it is not working.

```
export function GlobalMiddleware(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
 
 try {
    next();
 } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
 }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation, catching all unhandled exceptions can be done using an [exception filter](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters).

You can learn more about how to use a global exception filter on the documentation as there is a section about it: https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters#catch-everything

Answer (score 0):

as [this github comment](https://github.com/nestjs/docs.nestjs.com/issues/215#issuecomment-774504957) maybe this work for you (it worked for me):

```js
export function GlobalMiddleware(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
 
 try {
    next();
 } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    next(error);
 }

}
```